# Using Sidekiq and Passenger in same Heroku Dyno

Tags: heroku, passenger, sidekiq

I have a simple web app on heroku running on Passenger and I am trying to make the emails asynchronous. I set it all up with Sidekiq in my dev environment and then I realized I have to start a new dyno on Heroku to run the Sidekiq worker and have to pay $34/m. I am trying to see if I can run Sidekiq on the web dyno with Passenger and save the $34/m cost for now till its worth that investment.

I found a post [here](https://coderwall.com/p/fprnhg) that explains how to do this with Unicorn. I am wondering if I can do the same thing with Passenger.

If that doesn't work I will look at using sucker_punch or use unicorn instead but will be good if I can Sidekiq working on the same dyno with Passenger.

I am on rails 3.1, sidekiq 3.1.4 and passenger 4.0.5 - can upgrade here if I have to.

Thanks for your thoughts.

-S

Answer (score 0):

You can. There's no difference between Passenger and Unicorn when it comes to achieving this goal. Instead of specifying `web: bundle exec unicorn ...` in your Procfile, you just set `web: bundle exec passenger` in your Procfile. Instead of setting a Unicorn config file, you set equivalent Passenger command line arguments or configuration.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with Passenger. When I make the changes suggested for Unicorm for Passenger I get an error saying the concurrency feature is available only in Enterprise version of Passenger which I have to pay for. I switched to using Unicorn with suggested changes in the link my earlier post.

Comment: Concurrency feature? Why did you try to turn on the concurrency feature in Phusion Passenger? It is not needed at all to be able to be able to run Sidekiq. Sidekiq works just fine without you having to use the Enterprise version.

Comment: I did exactly as you suggested and used the unicorn.rb file from the link in my post to create a passenger.rb file. Which is when I go the concurrency error. I then commented out the first line of the passenger.rb file "worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)" to see if that could resolve but it did not. I couldn't figure out how to avoid the Passenger concurrency issue so I moved to Unicorn. If you can let me know how to avoid that, that will be very helpful. Thanks.